# Is there anyway to debug a Chainlink Functions request that returns 'Fulfilled with error'?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, chainlink

When sending a request to Chainlink Functions 'DON' from a functions consumer contract, my transaction is successful and the subscription is charged, however I do not receive the data requested from the API. When reviewing the subscription manager 'Recent Fulfillments' the status of the fulfilment is 'Fulfilled with error'.

It also appears that the API call is not being made by the DON, there are no new API calls registered at the API end.

[image]

I have tried reducing the gas usage on the returning contract, this did not work. I expected this was not the problem due to the fact that I have this same contract working on the original BETA version of Chainlink Functions contracts from about 6 months ago.

I have encoded the secret API key as per instructions using the secrets manager and also the source code is correct.

Below Links to the subscription and verified contract.

[Chainlink Functions Subscription](https://functions.chain.link/mumbai/888)

[Functions Consumer contract on Polygonscan Mumbai](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xF26e7C782728767A8A4dC1a309aCbA5326731231)

JS script for the functions request:

```js
const plot = args[0];
var verifiedString = "";

var regex = /^\/{0,}(?:[^0-9`~!@#$%^&*()+\-_=[{\]}\\|'<,.>?/";:£§º©®\s]+[.｡。･・︒។։။۔።।][^0-9`~!@#$%^&*()+\-_=[{\]}\\|'<,.>?/";:£§º©®\s]+[.｡。･・︒។։။۔።।][^0-9`~!@#$%^&*()+\-_=[{\]}\\|'<,.>?/";:£§º©®\s]+|[^0-9`~!@#$%^&*()+\-_=[{\]}\\|'<,.>?/";:£§º©®\s]+([\u0020\u00A0][^0-9`~!@#$%^&*()+\-_=[{\]}\\|'<,.>?/";:£§º©®\s]+){1,3}[.｡。･・︒។։။۔።।][^0-9`~!@#$%^&*()+\-_=[{\]}\\|'<,.>?/";:£§º©®\s]+([\u0020\u00A0][^0-9`~!@#$%^&*()+\-_=[{\]}\\|'<,.>?/";:£§º©®\s]+){1,3}[.｡。･・︒។։။۔።।][^0-9`~!@#$%^&*()+\-_=[{\]}\\|'<,.>?/";:£§º©®\s]+([\u0020\u00A0][^0-9`~!@#$%^&*()+\-_=[{\]}\\|'<,.>?/";:£§º©®\s]+){1,3})$/;

if (plot.length > 64) {
    throw Error(`Request Failed: Too many characters in request`)
}

// Check for regular expressions
if (!regex.test(plot)) {
    throw Error(`Request Failed: Not a correctly formatted plot name`)
}

// build HTTP request objects
// API call to GET the words address location info using the supplied words address in any language. 
// If the supplied words address is incorrect the API will revert with an error. 
const request = Functions.makeHttpRequest({
    url: `https://api.what3words.com/v3/convert-to-coordinates`,
    headers: { "X-Api-Key": secrets.apiKey },
    params: {
        words: plot,
    },
})

// Wait for all requests to finish
const response = await request;

// Verify if there are any errors in responses

if (response.error || response.Response === "Error") {
    throw Error(`Request Failed: Code: ${response.code} Message: ${response.message}`);
}
else if (response["data"]["language"] != "en") {
    const lat = response["data"]["coordinates"]["lat"]
    const lng = response["data"]["coordinates"]["lng"]
    const coordinates = `${lat},${lng}`

    const enRequest = Functions.makeHttpRequest({
        url: `https://api.what3words.com/v3/convert-to-3wa`,
        // Get a free API key from https://accounts.what3words.com/create-api-key/
        headers: { "X-Api-Key": secrets.apiKey },
        params: {
            coordinates: coordinates,
            language: "en",
        },
    })

    const enResponse = await enRequest;
    if (enResponse.error || enResponse.Response === "Error") {
        throw Error(`Request Failed: Code: ${enResponse.code} Message: ${enResponse.message}`);
    }
    else if (enResponse["data"]["language"] != "en") {
        throw Error(`Request Failed: Code: 400  Message: BadLanguage`);
    }
    else {
        verifiedString = enResponse.data.words;
    }
}
else {
    verifiedString = response.data.words;
}

// throw an error if verifiedString is empty
if (verifiedString.length == 0) {
    throw Error(`Request Failed: API result empty.`)
}

return Functions.encodeString(`${verifiedString}`)
```

Comment: hey Vince, need more info on this to diagnose.  The s_lastError on your contract is empty bytes (as is s_lastResponse).  Can you share your custom JS?  Also, have you tried running simulating your JS Script (ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@chainlink/functions-toolkit#local-functions-simulator) ?

Comment: Hi Zeus, yes they are both empty as no response is being received from the DON. The JS script works fine when simulating. I'll add the JS to the question details. Thanks

Comment: interesting -- how long is your response string in the simulation?  is it greater than 256 bytes? That is the current upper bound on default return valye size.

Comment: It is interesting but it appears I am not the only person experiencing this issue on Discord. As stated there is no call being made to the API from the DON so not return can be made, if it was to return a value from the API it would be less than 256 bytes.

Comment: Hi Vince, can you provide more details that will help reproduce? I've seen only one other person with this issue and none at EthGlobal so its either an edge case or a misconfig.  Need more info to diagnose.

Comment: Hi Zeuz, The best way to see whats happening is to send a request on the contract "verifyPlot" function with a what3words address and then check the subscription manager and contract transactions, however this is a payable function so you may not wish to use it, the payment value can be identified by using the 'checkPrice' function and then add a bit for gas price fluctuations, the 'verifyPlot' function refunds any overpayment in the same transaction, also when the response is not received from the DON for more than 1 hour there is a 'requestRefund' function that can be used for refund. cheers

Comment: I may stop paying for the API key soon as I am moving onto another option to remove the requirement for off-chain computation. I'll leave it here and hopefully someone will figure it out in the future. Cheers